# Excel Comparision to find the range of number

Tags: excel, vba

Hello Please consider my silly question, I am stuck here since a long time

ElseIf Cells(m1, a) >= 1 And Cells(m1, a) <= 98 Then

Cells(m1, a).Font.Bold = True

here only the values without decimal point (eg. 4,56,90)etc are getting bold, values with decimal point (4.5,56.5,90.54) despite being in the rqnge are not getting filtered.

Please suggest possible problem

I think the problem is with French numbering system as the data coming is from France.

Thank you

Is there any way to consider different numbering system, with the US system....???

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Cells(m1,a).value` as well as `Cells(m1,a).value`

The code below will examine the list of cell are selected before the macro is run. For each cell, if it's value is [1..98] then I take the state and toggle it.

```
Sub toggleBoldInSelection()
    Dim cellValue
    For Each curCell In Selection
        cellValue = curCell.Value
        If (cellValue >= 1) And (cellValue <= 98) Then
            curCell.Font.Bold = Not curCell.Font.Bold 'True
        End If
    Next curCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ElseIf Val(Cells(m1, a).Value) >= 1 And Val(Cells(m1, a).Value) <= 98 Then
```

If you are not running this code from the sheet code area then do not forget to fully qualify the cells object. For example

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(m1, a).Value
```

Comment: The problem was with french numbering system :P